# How do I (recursively) search ALL file contents in Windows 7?

Tags: search, windows-7, recursion

How do I (recursively) search **all** file contents in Windows 7? I am using the `content:xxx` command, in the `Search settings` box in Windows Explorer, to search `xxx` in this example. This does not work:

As an example of how this search is broken, I see an `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file with text that I am searching for and Windows 7 is not returning it in the results. I assume it's only searching known text-based file types. **How can I make it search all files**? I need to find everything I am looking for.

P.S. If there is a DOS-based solution, I will also accept this. Maybe a batch file using `dir /s /b` and `findstr` could be constructed.

*EDIT: Noted my need for a recursive search.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my **three file** DOS solution, but I am still looking for a proper Windows 7 solution if anyone has one:

## 1. search.bat

```
@ECHO off
FOR /r %%a IN (*.*) DO CALL process.bat %%a
```

Searches **all** files recursively, and runs `process.bat` on each one.

## 2. process.bat

```
@ECHO Off
ECHO "%1" >> output.txt
TYPE "%1" | FINDSTR /i "search_string_here" >> output.txt
```

Prints out the name of each file, in quotes because some files will break the batch file code without, then finds the search string, `search_string_here`, and prints out the entire line that the search string is found in.

## 3. output.txt (sample output)

Contains the output, formatted as follows, searching `search_string_here` in my `project_name` Java project stored in `D:\project_name\`, displaying all files searched as well as results if there are some:

```
"D:\project_name\.classpath" 
"D:\project_name\.project" 
    <name>search_string_here</name>
"D:\project_name\content_search_all_files.bat" 
"D:\project_name\output.txt" 
    <name>search_string_here</name>
"D:\project_name\pom.xml" 
...
```

Above you can see that `search_string_here` was found, full line being `<name>search_string_here</name>`, in `D:\project_name\.project` file... among other results.

Again, I am still looking for a proper Windows 7 solution if anyone has one.

## Warning: "Line is too long" Errors; FINDSTR may be buggy:

Apparently, FINDSTR < grep, as if you didn't know. Here's an article that dives into the error in FINDSTR that are do not reproduce when the same input is used in a different file:

> Obviously, “line is too long” is a catch-all message for a number of
>   different errors. FINDSTR has some issues.  Some time ago, I said that
>   FINDSTR was marginally useful.  After today, I’d say it’s even less
>   useful than I thought it was then.
>   - http://blog.mischel.com/2008/10/14/copying-large-files-on-windows/

Comment: +1 This works well.  I made a couple of slight improvements: changing the first file to say `process.bat %%a %1`, and the second file to `FINDSTR /i "%2"`; and changing the path to `process.bat` to `%~dp0\process.bat`.  The first change allows me to pass in the search string from the command-line instead of it being hard-coded.  The second parameter allows me to run the search routine from a different directory without having to copy the two batch files around everywhere I want to search.  Cheers :)

Comment: Ha ha ha, epic. I love the fact that the search in W7 is so bad that people are resorting to DOS. Typical MS, I can still picture Bill Gates (on SurfaceRT) sitting there saying "it's a tablet - with a stand". A stand!

Answer (score 44):

"user3245549" is right:

All of the above answers with "for loops" and nested bat files are mumbo jumbo. All you need is to just use "findstr" - example:

```
C:\temp> findstr /S /C:"/work" * | more   <-- this will find the string "/work" in any file
```

or

```
C:\temp> findstr /S /C:"/work" "*.*" | more
```

or

```
C:\temp> findstr /S /C:"/work" * > results.txt
```

or

```
C:\temp> findstr /S /C:"/work" "*.*" > results.txt
```

NOTE: You can leave out the "double-quotes" around the asterisks - I just put those because the editor here on Stackoverflow was stripping out the asterisks on either side of the period.
NOTE ALSO: You still need the quotes around the "string text" for which you are searching, as far as I know.

Comment: Isn't the reason people use the for loop, because findstr can't display the full path for each search result - making recursive search results useless?

Comment: Use `/I` to ignore case. You will need it. Check here: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Comment: I was using this without `*` to ignore type, now it seems very necessary, because without `*` it returns nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

If you are looking for a GUI-based solution where you don't have to remember the syntax, try out Notepad++. There is a Search menu which lets you search files in a directory (find in files), limit it to certain extensions (filter), and look in subfolders, and then you just click on the item in the list and it opens that file for edit.

Comment: Oh, I just found in Sublime Text 3 it's also possible, to save your time, the hotkey is Ctrl+Shift+F. Viola!

Comment: Easy and quick compared to Command Prompt search

Comment: Definitely the way, other answers did not work for me. Plus clicking on a result to go to the line in the file is super convenient

Answer (score 8):

Use the findstr command from a command prompt window.

/s give you a recursive search

/i ignores case

Answer (score 4):

This can be done through the command prompt, though the syntax is quite verbose

```
for /r %a in (\*.*) do find "search_text" %a
```

This now works in Windows 7 (extra dot removed)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a file or folder located in a common folder (such as Documents or Pictures), you can often find it fastest by using the Search box at the top of the folder window. For more information, see Use the Search box.[Here.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tips-for-finding-files#search)

If you're looking for a program, a website in your browser history, or a file that you've stored anywhere in your personal folder, you can use the Search box at the bottom of the Start menu. For more information, see Find a file or folder.[Here.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Find-a-file-or-folder)

If you're looking for several related files, such as all the files from a particular month, or all the documents that you have written, you can use the headings above the file list to filter, stack, or group your files. Organizing your files in one of these ways makes them easier to locate and select. For more information, see Use file list headings.[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tips-for-finding-files#column)

When you need to build a search with multiple filters, or when you're looking for files from several folders at once, create your search in the Search folder. When you are done, you can save the search criteria, and use it in the future to find the same set of files again with a single click. For more information, see Create an advanced search in the Search folder.[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tips-for-finding-files#advanced)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but I am not searching for common or related files or programs, I am searching the *contents* of uncommon files, such as the one I give in my example, and I need to search the contents of all files, recursively. I will modify my question to better explain the recursive need of my search. But, thank you. If you can help me out more, please do.

Comment: Voted down the answer for copying and pasting from Windows forum. At least seems like it.